# How to convert this form in Rails to Ajax/JavaScript/jQuery so it doesn't need to be submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've created a form in Rails that calculates the Gross Profit Margin Percent based on an input of Price.

A user selects the related product on the form and then inputs a price in the field of `deal_price`.

Then a callback goes and queries the cost from the `Price` model.

A basic calculation is performed and this value is populated into `deal_price_gp`

Is there anyway this can be done with JavaScript/AJAX/jQuery so the user does not have to submit the form?

```
class Calculator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  before_save :calculate_gp

  def calculate_gp

    price = Price.where(:product_id => self.product_id).first

    self.deal_price_gp = (self.deal_price - price.deal_cost) / self.deal_price if self.deal_price.present?

  end

end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried?  There are a lot of resources to help with this on SO and other websites.

Comment: Nothing just yet, was hoping to get some direction from SO. Any ideas mate? Thanks

Comment: Yes @bnussey.  I googled "Rails ajax" and found several excellent resources that are very easy to follow.  SO is best suited for solving specific problems, which you may or may not have once you try to do this yourself.  You will get a lot more (and better) support if you show some effort before posting a question.

Comment: Hey @steveklein understood.. well the most challenging thing is working out how to get the cost value from the Price Model into the JS.. any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Just like any HTML form, you can tag form elements with an `id` or `class`.  Once you do this, you can reference that element in JS by its id or class.

Comment: Hey mate, so I need to get a value from a different table in the DB, that is the challenge

Comment: You voted my question down but clearly didn't even read it properly..

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of parseFloat and .toFixed() which will round off to two decimal places:

```js
$('#deal_price, #deal_cost').change(function(){
    var price = parseFloat($('#deal_price').val());
    var cost = parseFloat($('#deal_cost').val());
    var gp = ((price - cost)/price).toFixed(2);
    $('#deal_price_gp').val(gp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" placeholder="Price" id="deal_price">
<input type="number" placeholder="Cost" id="deal_cost">
<input type="number" placeholder="GP" id="deal_price_gp">
```

Comment: Hey @oMiKeY i think the issue with this is I need to somehow get the deal_cost value from the Price model -- how can that be done through JavaScript? In my callback I query it based on the product_id which is shared across both models. Thanks for your answer mate.